# Position of a race result using database query?

Tags: mysql, time

The scenario is based around a race event (running/jogging)

Is there a way of getting a position of a person by using their race results. For example the quickest person to finish a race would be in a seperate table of race position with the value of 1. The second quickest person would get a result of 2, and so on. Just by using the race result of that individual (Data Type - Time).

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a variable and CROSS JOIN it with your table. You should increment the variable value for each returned record.

Keep in mind you need to set the correct order on your subquery.

```
order by duration asc
```

I've set up the next example:

```
drop table if exists course;
create table if not exists course(id int, duration time);
insert into course values
(1, '01:20:00'),
(2, '01:21:02'),
(3, '01:19:02'),
(4, '01:22:02'),
(5, '01:17:05'),
(6, '01:23:02'),
(7, '01:12:02'),
(8, '01:16:02'),
(9, '01:15:02');


select id, duration, @position := @position +  1 as position
from
       (select @position := 0) x,
       (select id, duration
        from course
        order by duration asc) y;


drop table if exists course;
```

And this is the result:

```
| id | duration | position |
|---:|---------:|----------|
| 7  | 01:12:02 | 1        |
| 9  | 01:15:02 | 2        |
| 8  | 01:16:02 | 3        |
| 5  | 01:17:05 | 4        |
| 3  | 01:19:02 | 5        |
| 1  | 01:20:00 | 6        |
| 2  | 01:21:02 | 7        |
| 4  | 01:22:02 | 8        |
| 6  | 01:23:02 | 9        |
```

Rextester [here](http://rextester.com/ALW85468).

Comment: Amazing stuff! Thankyou, very easily laid out too!

Comment: I'm glad to be able to help.